# NetCDF format to OpenLayers Map

Tags: maps, netcdf

I have a very large dataset (800mb+) that I would like to serve to my OpenLayers map. The data is in the NetCDF format. I am not familiar with this format and am looking for ways to serve this data. I have looked into using GeoServer, Map Server and MapNik, but GeoServer seems to be the only possibility via a plugin.

Is there a solution out there using NetCDF files to display data within the browser outside of the ArcGis realm?

I asked a [similar question at GIS.StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110584/need-advice-displaying-very-large-amounts-of-data-on-leaflet-js-from-database), but am thinking I'd get more responses possibly here.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I can't give an exact answer, but have you looked at this list for a possible solution? http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html

Answer (score 2):

OpenLayers can access and display data from an OGC Web Mapping Service (WMS). So you might try using [ncWMS](https://github.com/Reading-eScience-Centre/ncwms) to serve your netCDF data.

It does require that your netCDF files have enough information so that the [netCDF-java library](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-java/current/userguide/index.html) can recognize them as gridded data. ToolsUI (which is part of the netCDF-java library, the toolsUI.jar) is a good tool to check if your data is recognized as a grid.

Just try to open your data files in the "FeatureTypes -> Grids" tab of ToolsUI. If it is recognized as gridded data you'll see information in each of the three tables in the main window. The top table lists the variables that were recognized as grids.

If that works, you should be good to serve your data with ncWMS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Fixed the ncWMS link. the Java library link is also broken

Comment: Fixed the netCDF-java link